# Detect version of Apache2 in shell script

Tags: apache, ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

I am creating a `deb` package that depends on `apache2`. I would like my package to work on all recent versions of Debian and Ubuntu, therefore it should work with both Apache 2.2 and 2.4.

What is an elegant way to detect the version of `apache2`?

```
ISAP22=$(apache2 -v | grep "Apache/2.2")
if [ "$ISAP22" ]; then
  #asssume apache 2.2
else
  #assume apache 2.4
fi
```

This works in a bash script, but when I put this in my `.postinst` the package installation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `dpkg` with `--compare-versions`:

```
APACHE_VERSION=$(dpkg -l | awk '$2 ~ /apache2(-prefork)?-dev/ { print $3 }')
echo "Found Apache version $APACHE_VERSION"
if dpkg --compare-versions $APACHE_VERSION lt 2.4; then
    echo "Patching config for Apache 2.2"
fi
```

Comment: `dpkg -l apahce2-*dev` would be more efficient but an inherent problem with `dpkg -l` is that it will truncate long version numbers.  You can fiddle with `COLUMNS` to make it print these fields really wide, or you can use `dpkg -s apache2-dev apache2-prefork-dev 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Version: / { print $2 }'`